# Get-Acl : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to archive some old folders from our share to the archive share but when running the script i got the following error :

```
Get-Acl : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'

PS C:\> C:\movefiles.ps1
112256

Get-Acl : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At C:\movefiles.ps1:15 char:19
+ $get_acl = Get-Acl <<<<  $files.FullName | ft $files.FullName | out-file $logfile -append 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Acl], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\movefiles.ps1:18 char:25
+ $Files = Copy-Item -Path <<<<  $files -Recurse -Destination $new_document_share -force
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

The script i build :

```
$logfile = �C:\Scriptlog\logs.txt
$old_document_share = \\server\sharedfolder
$new_document_share = \\server\archive\2019
$date_time = Get-Date -Format g
$names_account = (Get-Content C:\orderstomove.csv) -split �,�
foreach ($account_name in $names_account)
{
# copy foldersmatchthat match account name
write-host $account_name 

$files = Get-ChildItem $old_document_share\* | Where-Object{($_.psiscontainer -eq $true) -and ($_.name.Contains($account_name))}
    foreach ($files in $folders)
    {
    write-host $files
    $get_acl = Get-Acl $files.FullName | ft $files.FullName | out-file $logfile -append 
    $output_details = $date_time | out-file $logfile -append
    #copy with folder structure
    $Files = Copy-Item -Path $files -Recurse -Destination $new_document_share -force
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `Path` is null or empty? Thats what the error suggests.

Comment: Your foreach loop is wrong. You have an array `$files` which you should iterate through, not the undefined`$folders` variable. Inside the loop, you misuse the `$files` variable again on `Copy-Item`..

Comment: `foreach($files in $folders)` -> `foreach($files in $folders |Get-ChildItem |? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false})`

Comment: Probaly i understood wrong but i tried both options and were getting errors..  i replaced the foreach loop and i'm 100 % sure the path is not empty...